# Writing a structured Om application with requests, but not om.next

Tags: clojurescript, om

I'd like to write an application in Om - a GitHub issues viewer in particular. To retrieve issues from GitHub, I'll need to XHR request them, and there'll be the action of marking issues as 'viewed' by sending a request back to GitHub.

There's quite a bit of documentation for using the current version of Om without async/http calls, and quite a bit for using Om.next with them, but I'm just getting started and feel like Om.next isn't the right place for a complete ClojureScript newbie to dive in.

Is there documentation and are there patterns for using the current stable version of Om (0.8.x) with remote resources, that'd lead to a clean architecture for this kind of app? The big applications that are using Om in production, like CircleCI - are they using Om.next? If not, what's the commonly-accepted pattern for requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that you can dive in om's [real-world example](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Intermediate-Tutorial). They are using Google Closure's [XhrIo](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/xhrio) for async http calls.

```
(defn edn-xhr [{:keys [method url data on-complete]}]
  (let [xhr (XhrIo.)]
    (events/listen xhr goog.net.EventType.COMPLETE
      (fn [e]
        (on-complete (reader/read-string (.getResponseText xhr)))))
    (. xhr
      (send url (meths method) (when data (pr-str data))
        #js {"Content-Type" "application/edn"}))))
```

Communicating server on user change

```
(defn on-edit [id title]
  (edn-xhr
    {:method :put
     :url (str "class/" id "/update")
     :data {:class/title title}
     :on-complete
     (fn [res]
       (println "server response:" res))}))
```

Data loading on `om.core/IWillMount`

```
(defn classes-view [app owner]
  (reify
    om/IWillMount
    (will-mount [_]
      (edn-xhr
        {:method :get
         :url "classes"
         :on-complete #(om/transact! app :classes (fn [_] %))}))
    om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (dom/div #js {:id "classes"}
        (dom/h2 nil "Classes")
        (apply dom/ul nil
          (map
            (fn [class]
              (let [id (:class/id class)]
                (om/build editable class
                  {:opts {:edit-key :class/title
                          :on-edit #(on-edit id %)}})))
            (:classes app)))))))
```

This is not answer for your question, but you can dive in om examples

Answer (score 2):

CircleCI frontend is currently written in Om, but [they have plans to migrate to Om.next](http://blog.circleci.com/why-we-use-om-and-why-were-excited-for-om-next/), and they explain why.

Regarding Om, there is a repository dedicated to ["idioms and patterns"](https://github.com/omcljs/om-cookbook), linked from the [tutorial section](https://github.com/omcljs/om/tree/om-528#tutorials). I would not say that anything is written in marble though, be prepared to experiment a bit.